# Short story about a man meeting a pig farmer who is named Circe found in anthology possibly based on the seven deadly sins

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story in an anthology about a man who stops at a farm owned by a young woman who owns pigs.  At the end we find out her name is Circe.  I thought it was in a collection about the seven deadly sins...

Comment: Approximately when did you read this?

Answer (score 5):

This could be "Mrs. Hawk" by [Margaret St. Clair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_St._Clair).

It was originally published in the 1950 July issue of [Weird Tales](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Weird_Tales/1950#July) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Weird_Tales_British_Ed._1950-07_Missing_ibcbc#page/n77/mode/2up)), and as @user14111 has pointed out, re-published in [The Unexpected](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?49072). Neither of them seem to be about the seven deadly sins.

I can't find the original story, but Episode #50 of [Thriller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thriller_(U.S._TV_series)#Season_2:_1961.E2.80.931962) was based on it and its script can be found [here](http://www.oocities.org/emruf7/hawk.html).

From the script there is a pig farm

> EXT. **HOG FARM** - NIGHT - FULL SHOT - (STOCK)
> Sparkling white house and outbuildings, neat fences and
> pens, etc., set back from the road which winds pleasantly
> through the moonlit valley below.

And that Mrs. Hawk is actually the  [Greek Goddess Circe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circe):

> I, Cissy Hawk, do confess that
> I am actually **Circe**, the Greek
> sorceress who changed sailors
> of Ulysses into hogs.

Comment: Google is not your friend but the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?88021) is. "Mrs. Hawk" was reprinted in a paperback anthology called [*The Unexpected*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?49072).

Comment: The [TV script](http://www.oocities.org/emruf7/hawk.html) you linked to is a greatly expanded version of [Margaret St. Clair](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?237)'s little story [Mrs. Hawk](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?88021), with a lot of additional characters and incidents. Here's what happens in the text story, as reprinted in [*The Unexpected*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?49072): Because Norman Vesh and Andrew Fruness, two young men who answered Mrs. Hawk's "matrimonial ads", are missing persons, Sheriff Willets is investigating Mr. Hawk and her hog farm. . .

Comment: . . . He suspects her of witchcraft since he read about the Circe myth in his son's mythology book. When she offers refreshments, he switches drinks with her but falls for the poisoned doughnut. All that other stuff, such as the signed confession you quoted, were added for the TV drama.